# CMD window is too big for the output

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a build operation running in cmd and it outputs information about processes and stack traces if there are any errors.

But the CMD window is way bigger than the output so normal scrolling (like with a scroll wheel) moves too slowly. And if you grip the scrollbar handle it becomes overly sensitive, moving too many lines at once making it difficult to find the beginning of the stack trace.

***How can I force the window to vertically adjust to the output?***

For example, you can open a new cmd window and see what I'm talking about:

[image]

The handle is tiny, so if you grab it and move it, it goes too fast and skips all the important output. In simpler terms, I'd like to force the window to adjust to the size of the output so the handle is bigger.

Comment: I'm not sure resizing the window will help. You might want to look at piping the results out to text file using `>` e.g. `dir/s > c:\dir.log`

Comment: Adjust how? If the output is 2000 lines long, should the window fit 2000 lines vertically? How about long lines, should the window scale horizontally to match line length? What if only 1 in those 2000 lines is very long, should the window adjust to that line or wrap it?

Comment: [`MORE` displays output one screen at a time](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html). Use e.g. as `dir /B/S | more`

Comment: @gronostaj The vertical is my concern. When scrolling up, to see a stack trace for instance, the handle is small relative to the virtual height of the window, and most of the height is empty space after the output. This causes the speed at which I can scroll through the window to be very sensitive - if I go too fast I'll miss all the output. I'm wondering if there is some sort of command that forces the window to adapt to the output, trimming the excess empty space, ya know, like a normal window.

Comment: **`your_command | findstr .^[0-9-a-Z]*`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this running your command 2 times:

**1.** Count lines in the output command:

```
>your command |find/v /c ""
```

**2.** Increase +10 using `for /f` loop and `set /a`

```
for /f %i in (`your command^|find/v /c ""`)do set /a "_lines+=%~i+10"
```

**3.** Define your `mode con:` accordingly with `mode con: cols=135 lines=%_lines%`

```
...)do set /a ...  & call mode con: cols=135 lines=%_lines% ...
```

**4.** Run your command again

```
for /f %i in ('run your command ^|find/c /v ""')do set /a "_lines+=%~i+10" & call mode con: cols=135 lines=%_lines% && run your command again
```

---

- Example:

```
for /f %i in ('robocopy /?^|find/v /c ""')do set /a "_lines+=10+%i" & call mode con: cols=135 lines=%_lines% && robocopy /?
```

---

- Alternative command: `your command |more /E`

```
robocopy /? | more /e
```

- ***```
  If extended features are enabled, (/E) the following
  keystrokes can be used at the: -- More -- prompt:

        <space>   Display next page
        <return>  Display next line
        Q         Quit
        P n       Display next n lines
        S n       Skip next n lines
        F         Display next file
        =         Show line number
        ?         Show help line
  ```***

---

- Some further reading:

[√] **[`|Mode /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)**

[√] **[`|More /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html)**

[√] **[`|find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

[√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

[√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_F.html)**

[√] **[Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**